# Error message doesn't disappear when the field it's filled in

Tags: javascript, html

On my form I want to have an error message every time a field is not filled in, it actually works, but then when the field is filled in the message is still there.

I have a clue where the error may be, it must be right here, but I tried to change the names and hopefully make it right, but it didn't work and the form was sent anyway, like the JavaScript wasn't even there.

```
    nameError = "Please type your name";
    document.getElementById("nome_error").innerHTML = nameError;
```

Code:

```js
document.getElementById("contactos").onsubmit = function() {
  var nome = document.forms["contactos"]["NomeM"].value;
  var assunto = document.forms["contactos"]["Assunto"].value;
  var email = document.forms["contactos"]["EmailMen"].value;
  var mensagem = document.forms["contactos"]["Mensagem"].value;

  var submit = true;

  if (nome == null || nome == "") {
    nameError = "Please type your name";
    document.getElementById("nome_error").innerHTML = nameError;
    submit = false;
  }

  if (assunto == null || assunto == "") {
    emailError = "Please type the subject of your message";
    document.getElementById("assunto_error").innerHTML = emailError;
    submit = false;
  }

  if (email == null || email == "") {
    telephoneError = "Please type your email";
    document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = telephoneError;
    submit = false;
  }

  if (mensagem == null || mensagem == "") {
    telephoneError = "Please type your message";
    document.getElementById("mensagem_error").innerHTML = telephoneError;
    submit = false;
  }

  return submit;
}

function removeWarning() {
  document.getElementById(this.id + "_error").innerHTML = "";
}

document.getElementById("NomeM").onkeyup = removeWarning;
document.getElementById("Assunto").onkeyup = removeWarning;
document.getElementById("EmailMen").onkeyup = removeWarning;
document.getElementById("Mensagem").onkeyup = removeWarning;
```

```html
<section class="site-section bg-light" id="section-contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 text-center mb-5 site-animate">
        <h2 class="display-4">Contacte-nos</h2>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-7">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-7 mb-5 site-animate">
        <form action="index.php?cmd=contform" method="post" name="contactos" id="contactos">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="NomeM" class="sr-only">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeM" id="NomeM" name="NomeM" placeholder="Nome">
            <span class="error"><p id="nome_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Assunto" class="sr-only">Assunto</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Assunto" id="Assunto" name="Assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
            <span class="error"><p id="assunto_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="EmailMen" class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="EmailMen" name="EmailMen" placeholder="Email">
            <span class="error"><p id="email_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Mensagem" class="sr-only">Messagem</label>
            <textarea name="Mensagem" id="Mensagem" name="Mensagem" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem"></textarea>
            <span class="error"><p id="mensagem_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Mensagem">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>

      <?php 
   $sql="select * from Contactos";
   $res=$lig->query($sql);
   while($lin=$res->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<div class='col-md-4 site-animate'><p><img src='images/chef.jpg' alt='' class='img-fluid'></p>";
          echo "<p class='text-black'>Morada: <br> ".$lin['Morada']." <br> ".$lin['CodPostal']." <br> <br> ";
          echo " Telefone: <br> ".$lin['TelefoneCont']." <br> <br> Email: <br> ".$lin['EmailCont']." <br> <br> Fax: <br> ".$lin['Fax']." ";
   }
  
?>
      </p>

    </div>



  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Don't you see the error message when `removeWarning()` tries to empty the error field?

Comment: Ins't that supposed to "delete" the error message when the field is not empty anymore?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work, and the error message in the JavaScript console should help you understand why.

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**

Comment: then what can i do? Because a have another file white the same script and it works, i'm still new with javascript

Answer (score 0):

The `removeWarning()` function doesn't work. It expects the ID of the element with the error message to be the same as the ID of the input field, with `_error` appended. But the IDs don't match up like that. For the name field, the ID is `NomeM`, but the error field is `nome_error`, not `NomeM_error`.

Fix your IDs so that the they match properly and the code should work. Don't forget that IDs are case-significant.

BTW, there's no need to test whether the value is null. It's always a string.

```js
document.getElementById("contactos").onsubmit = function() {
  var nome = document.forms["contactos"]["NomeM"].value;
  var assunto = document.forms["contactos"]["Assunto"].value;
  var email = document.forms["contactos"]["EmailMen"].value;
  var mensagem = document.forms["contactos"]["Mensagem"].value;

  var submit = true;

  if (nome == "") {
    nameError = "Please type your name";
    document.getElementById("NomeM_error").innerHTML = nameError;
    submit = false;
  }

  if (assunto == "") {
    emailError = "Please type the subject of your message";
    document.getElementById("Assunto_error").innerHTML = emailError;
    submit = false;
  }

  if (email == "") {
    telephoneError = "Please type your email";
    document.getElementById("EmailMen_error").innerHTML = telephoneError;
    submit = false;
  }

  if (mensagem == "") {
    telephoneError = "Please type your message";
    document.getElementById("Mensagem_error").innerHTML = telephoneError;
    submit = false;
  }

  return submit;
}

function removeWarning() {
  document.getElementById(this.id + "_error").innerHTML = "";
}

document.getElementById("NomeM").onkeyup = removeWarning;
document.getElementById("Assunto").onkeyup = removeWarning;
document.getElementById("EmailMen").onkeyup = removeWarning;
document.getElementById("Mensagem").onkeyup = removeWarning;
```

```html
<section class="site-section bg-light" id="section-contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 text-center mb-5 site-animate">
        <h2 class="display-4">Contacte-nos</h2>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-7">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-7 mb-5 site-animate">
        <form action="index.php?cmd=contform" method="post" name="contactos" id="contactos">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="NomeM" class="sr-only">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeM" id="NomeM" name="NomeM" placeholder="Nome">
            <span class="error"><p id="NomeM_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Assunto" class="sr-only">Assunto</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Assunto" id="Assunto" name="Assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
            <span class="error"><p id="Assunto_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="EmailMen" class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="EmailMen" name="EmailMen" placeholder="Email">
            <span class="error"><p id="EmailMen_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Mensagem" class="sr-only">Messagem</label>
            <textarea name="Mensagem" id="Mensagem" name="Mensagem" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem"></textarea>
            <span class="error"><p id="Mensagem_error"></p></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Mensagem">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I uptated my file with the changes you made, but it still doesn't work

Comment: i think here: `nomeError = "Por favor introduza o seu nome";
        document.getElementById("NomeM_error").innerHTML = nomeError;` should also be NomeM, so i changed that, but it made no difference at all

Comment: It works in my snippet, I don't know what you're doing differently.

Comment: `NomeM_error` is correct, `NomeM` is the input field, not the error field.

Comment: i mean when it says `nomeError="Por favor introduza o seu nome` and `innerHTML=nomeError` shouldn't it also be `NomeM`?

Comment: so, i decided to copy the entire file to a different one, not on the same folder as my project  without the css and all of that, and it worked, now i don't know what 's actually wrong

Comment: Are you asking whether you need to change `nomeError` to something else? The variable name can be anything.

Comment: I don't think there's any errors, i tried on online compilers and everything worked fine

Comment: Is the server that doesn't work on the Internet so I can try it?

Comment: i use Bitviser client

Comment: I don't know what that is, google says it's an SSH client. But I'm asking about the web server.

Comment: Then I can't tell what's different between the original folder and when you copied it. Start using your browser's debugging tools to see what's going wrong.